# How to get netstream bytesLoaded and bytesTotal from streaming .mp4?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flashdevelop, mp4, netstream

I have a flex 3 app that uses netstream and a video object to stream .mp4 movies.  I want to use the bytesLoaded and bytesTotal properties of the netstream to display the buffering information.  I would also like to get any information about the number of frames that are dropped if possible.

When I've tested on .flv I'm able to get the information without a problem, but it doesn't seem to work on .mp4.

Is it possible to get this information streaming .mp4?  Is there some configuration that I'm missing to make things work the same for .mp4 as .flv?

Thanks!

edit: I should also mention that the streaming is done over RTMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that when using RTMP you can't get the byte information because the data isn't downloaded, it's purely streaming.

So instead I'm using the buffering info instead

```
Math.min(Math.round(ns.bufferLength/ns.bufferTime*100), 100);
```